# Automated tests with Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am new to PHP laravel framework.

My application is very basic:

- User first log-in with login and password (html form)
- The user can add items in a mysql table. This are numeric values. There are 2 controllers: One to see all rows and another to add/edit row
- Another Controller computes statistics (sum, average, etc.) on the numeric values stored in the table.

What i want do to is to test this application.

I want to write a test that:

- Creates an empty database
- Creates a user
- Log-in this user on my application
- Creates entries in my table throw my application (not directly in mysql)
- Check in the listing page if each entry has been created properly
- And i want to check if the statistics are good (check good values displayed on the webpage.

I have read about Testing section on Laravel's website documentation.

Here are my questions:

- I do not se how i can automated database initialization
- I do not see how i can check if a span or div contains a specific value (i only can test http response code and if webpage contains a given string).

I have worked with phpunit.

Thanks a lot

Comment: you rather should search this kind of data in php unit lib instead of laravel doc

Comment: not sure if you can test for divs and input values on phpunit ... if you want to test the frontend part and forms maybe use https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk

Comment: You can use one of these traits in your test to automate your tables initialization,  use DatabaseMigrations; use DatabaseTransactions; use RefreshDatabase; and to check for a specific element, you could simply use laravel dusk assertion methods, one the assertion comes to mind is ->assertSeeIn($selector, $text) to find a text by its selector.